# How to clear the DagRun object (<DagRun dag_id@2023-01-01 00:15:00+00:00:scheduled__2023-01-01T00:15:00+00:00, externally triggered: False>)

Tags: airflow, airflow-api

Goal is to find failed runs for some DAGs and trigger them (by clearing the scheduled run) programmatically without manual intervention.

I was able to retrieve the DagRun objects of failed runs using find function in class airflow.models.DagRun.

Is there a way we can use the below DagRun object to clear the run? Using Airflow version 1.10

<DagRun dag_id@2023-01-01 00:15:00+00:00:scheduled__2023-01-01T00:15:00+00:00, externally triggered: False>

Answer (score 0):

You can list the dagruns and then clear it with Airflow rest API

- List dagrun: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/stable-rest-api-ref.html#operation/get_dag_runs_batch
- Clear dagrun:
  https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/stable-rest-api-ref.html#operation/clear_dag_run

Comment: Thanks for your response.. The documentation says that these are the features of version 2.x. However, we are still using version 1.10.12 and upgrading to 2.x is not a feasible option for us as of now.